# Nav dropdown freaks out and shows different tabs

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm trying to create a navbar (already done) with a dropdown, but the dropdown keeps spazzing out when I hover over it :(

I made a JS Fiddle of what I've accomplished so far, and I was hoping for some help!

http://jsfiddle.net/kkpp6/

I think it might be due to the `display: none;` I used in one of the ul's or possibly due to a stupid typo but I can't figure out where!

As well as this, I can't figure out how to make a sub-menu for my sub-menus that already exist.. (so the desc tab has a submenu of swim squad which will also have a sub-menu of other things).. How would I do that? I can't figure out where I would start!

Cheers for all the help in advance!

Comment: " I can't figure out how to make a sub-menu for my sub-menus that already exist" --  You should bound an <ul><li>Your second level menu item</li></ul> tags to the sub menus that already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/kkpp6/2/)

**CSS:**

```
.nav-wrap {
    background-color: #125CC1;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.navigation-bar li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #125CC1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.navigation-bar li a:hover {
    background-color: #06398F;
}
ul.navigation-bar {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.navigation-bar li {
    line-height:28px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #125CC1;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.navigation-bar li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    width: 120px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul.navigation-bar li ul li {
    background: #125CC1;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
ul.navigation-bar li ul li:hover {
    background: #06398F;
    color: #fff;
}
ul.navigation-bar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

---

Updated fiddle **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/kkpp6/5/)**

Multi-level dropdown menu **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/kkpp6/7/)**

---

Comment: OMG! I love this man ^^, but I can't seem to find what you changed to make the original li's in the navigation bar hover so small and not the whole li element if you know what i mean? As well as this... how would I implement this for a further dropdown in one of those dropdowns?

Comment: updated my fiddle for hover width... and "further dropdown in one of those dropdowns" means u need one more sub level?

Comment: Yeah it does mean one more sub level

Answer (score 0):

On line 38, you set a list to display when the user hovers over a list item. This makes it visible, but also causes the entire menu to shift over so that you're no longer hovering over the list item that triggered that. If you use `position:absolute` on the list, it won't affect the other elements on the page:

```
ul.navigation-bar li > ul {
    position:absolute;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P9SUg/

Comment: Would I just then add margins or something to put it below.. or..?

Answer (score 0):

I also think its because of display:none;, instead of display:none; you should use visibility:hidden;.
and also add

`ul.navigation-bar li > ul {
    position:absolute;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do lot of changes in CSS for making dropdown menu.

```
 .nav-wrap {
background-color: #125CC1;
text-align: center;
}
ul.navigation-bar {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 ul.navigation-bar > li {
display: inline;
position:relative;
 }
 ul.navigation-bar > li > a {
display: inline-block;
width: 120px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #125CC1;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
transition: all 0.15s linear;
 }
 ul.navigation-bar > li > a:hover {
background-color: #06398F;
 }

 ul.navigation-bar ul {
display: none;
 }
 ul.navigation-bar li:hover > ul {
display: block;
position:absolute;
top:23px;
background-color:#ff00ff;
z-index:10;
width:100%;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 ul.navigation-bar li ul li a
 {
list-type:none;
text-align: left;
font-weight:normal;
padding: 4px;
font-size: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
transition: all 0.15s linear;
 }
 ul.navigation-bar li ul li:hover
{
background-color:#000;
}
 ul.navigation-bar li ul li:hover a
{
color:#fff;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kkpp6/3/)